# How to create a link in a row with @material-ui/data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am using @material-ui/data-grid to display some data and each row must have a link to the next page. I can pass all the required data, but am not sure how to create a link. The documentation doesn't mention it anywhere. I tried to pass it with the valueGetter like in the example below but due to how React renders HTML it just returns the href as a string.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    width: 150,
    valueGetter: (params) => 
      `<a href="${params.getValue("id")}">${params.getValue("id")}</a>`,
  },
  { field: "inviteId", headerName: "Invite Id", width: 150 },
];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're returning the link as a string:

```
`<a href="${params.getValue("id")}">${params.getValue("id")}</a>`
```

Could you not return this as JSX?

```
return (<a href={params.getValue("id")}>{params.getValue("id")}</a>)
```

### Update

The above is not correct as `valueGetter` is going to return a string.

It appears you will need to switch out `valueGetter` with `renderCell`, which allows you to render a React node. The Material UI docs provide an [example here](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#render-cell).

Comment: That renders it as a string as well "[object Object]"

Comment: It looks like you're right. It appears that valueGetter always returns a string. You will need to use renderCell (updated answer).

Comment: The link is broken. Here is the correct link https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link

Comment: The link is broken, but it has actually moved here: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#render-cell

Answer (score 4):

Updated.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) => 
      <a href="${params.row.id}">${params.row.id}</a>,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked for me.

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: 'id',
    headerName: 'ID',
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return <a href='${params.id}'>${params.id}</a>;
    },
  },
  { field: 'inviteId', headerName: 'Invite Id', width: 150 },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) => (
      <a href={`/form/${params.value}`}>{params.value}</a>
    ) 
},];
```